# Is there a compact metrizable non-abelian torsion-free group?

Tags: topological-groups

It is quite difficult to google for non-abelian torsion-free groups.

I am primarily interested in metrizable (''not too big'') compact groups. However, even if we drop the metrizability condition I do not know the answer.

Comment: The Heisenberg group over the $p$-adic ring $\mathbf{Z}_p$.

Comment: @YCor Thanks! That is correct.
I posted [a question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419127/compact-lie-groups-as-quotients-of-torsion-free-compact-metrizable-groups) that tells more about my motivation.